# Uncaught TypeError: store.put is not a function at store.onsuccess

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I can't update any data in IndexedDb. When I run the code it says "store.put is not a function at store.onsuccess".

- I tried from many browsers, same error in all
- I also tried .update instead of .put function but it didn't work and
  gave the same error

```
const request = window.indexedDB.open("AdminDatabase");

    request.onsuccess = (event) => {
      const db = event.target.result;

      const txn = db.transaction('floors', 'readwrite');

      const store = txn.objectStore('floors').get(parseInt(getRoomButtonNumber));
    
      store.onsuccess = function (event) {
        var floorDataFromDb = event.target.result;
        console.log("RenameFloor: getDbResult: FloorName: " + floorIdFromDb.Name);

        floorDataFromDb.Name = person;

        console.log("RenameFloor: Json New Name: " + floorDataFromDb.Name);

        //In this line caught error

        store.put(floorDataFromDb);

        store.onsuccess = function (event) {
          console.log("floorData Updated: " + event.target.result);

        }


      };

      store.onerror = function (event) {
        console.log("GET Error DB: " + event);

      };
    };
```

[IndexedDb Browser View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcYmb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You issue is on this line:
`const store = txn.objectStore('floors').get(parseInt(getRoomButtonNumber));`

You define store as an [`IDBRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/IDBRequest).

Obviously, this does not have a put method. You would instead change it to this:

```js
const store = txn.objectStore('floors');

const res = store.get(parseInt(getRoomButtonNumber));

res.onsuccess = evt => {
  ...
  store.put(data, key);
  ...
}

res.onerror = evt => {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention on which line the error was caught. There is no problem with the part you mentioned.  store.put(floorDataFromDb);" It gives an error for the command that writes.  Still I tried the solution you said and it didn't work. The error appears again in the line I mentioned.

Comment: I've updated my code so it reflects that you need to do `store.put`. You also need to have a key for the data.

Comment: It didn't work, same error again.

Comment: Could you add the error to your question?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: res.put is not a function at res.onsuccess

Comment: I made a mistake. It worked when I tried your answer again. Thank you!